# What's the implied noun in "o la va o la spacca"?

Tags: etymology, pronouns

The phrase "o la va o la spacca" means something like English "it's make or break", as I understand it.

What is the noun implied by (I assume) direct object pronoun "la"? Is it "la testa"?

Comment: What the noun implied by “it” in “it's make or break”? And what's made or broken?  :)

Comment: English has the dummy pronoun, differently from Italian. Nothing is implied by the dummy pronoun, when used; it is only necessary because sentences like *Piove.* in English requires a subject, which cannot be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "o la va o la spacca" would be translated as "it either works or it fails". The phrase subject is the done attempt.

Comment: Usually, “la spacca” doesn't mean at all “it fails”; it's just in this idiom that it assumes that meaning.

Comment: Yes, the phrase gets translated so, not the single nouns.

Comment: Yes, I know. I thought you didn't know this, since you say “the subject is an attempt”.

Comment: Why? Isn't that right?

Comment: I guess @Qualcuno2 means *The phrase subject is the done attempt.*

Comment: @apaderno thanks for the tip!

Comment: It is not that simple to explain *O la va o la spacca.* I could say *Voglio chiedere a Luisa se esce con me. Ma sì, o la va lo la spacca.* *O la va o la spacca.* is not understood to have its own subject, but it references what previously said.

Comment: @apaderno but the thing that was previously said was a try/attempt, right? Il tentativo risce--> Luisa accetta, quindi la va, altrimenti la spacca

Comment: It expresses a wish or what a person plans to do; it does not describe what the person tried to do, but eventually what that person will try to do. What I meant is that *O la va lo la spacca.* is not understood as referring to a "subject" that is totally different from what the previous sentence is referring. I did not mean the answer was not correct.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that, from some point of view, you can say that the implied noun
is "the deal" / "the matter"
i.e.: in italian you can translate it as
"la faccenda"

the answer to the question: "how did it go?"
may be "the deal went well!"
that can be translated
"(la faccenda) e' andata bene!" or more commonly just "E' andata!"

A few pages state its origin is not known, but maybe it was first used by people playing dice in ancient Rome - while
according to [this page](http://www.museociclismo.it/content/articoli/234-Storia+di+Domenico+Piemontesi/index.html) , it seems that  its origin can instead be linked to a road bicycle racer
from the early decades of last century.
But again no hint about why the verb "spaccare" is used here

Comment: From the first linked page, I do not gather the phrase etymology comes from cycle sport. The article just says that Domenico Piemontesi's temperament can be described with a phrase (*o la va o la spacca*).